# Bad Validation on ADB2C Login

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

When I log in to a web app secured with ADB2C, the login page displays with some pre-filled information (as I've told my browser to do). When I directly click the Sign In button, errors are displayed, as can be seen in the attached image. I can click the button again and the login continues. But this is a bad user experience. Is there a simple way to fix this?

I should note that I have another we app, using another ADB2C tenant, where this behavior is not observed--it works as expected. I don't know what possibly could be the difference.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is the "Page Layout Version." I don't know when the problem was introduced, but it is incorrect in 2.1.17. It does work when changed back to 2.1.5. A version between those must have introduced this bug.

Comment: Can you add an issue to the GitHub repository stating this? From the [Page contracts Learn documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/page-layout) click to submit feedback about 'this' page with the GitHub icon at the bottom of the documentation.

Comment: @bolt-io ... Not sure if that's the right place or not, but I did go ahead and submit the info there.